# API call Using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have created an object using `CreateObject("TriggeredSend")` and have added all appropriate properties for that object.

When I run the code, ExactTarget returns

```
CreateObject function is invalid. this function is valid only in non sendable content
```

[This page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/) reads:

We are creating this call in a content area, and using it in an email.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is basically telling you that you can't start a triggered email inside an email send. The reason for this would be that if you're sending to 1000 subscriber's then you'll be running 1000 API calls which in turn would send 1000 triggered emails. It's not best practice and has been disabled in the system. In order to use the API AMPScript to start a Triggered Send you will need to do this inside a landing page.